# How to unmerge the rows in Cross table of Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

[image: pot]

As in the image of Cross table, i want to show "Protocol Status" column values in each row(as of now its merged) . How to unmerge it to show in all rows rather then the single one?

Answer (score 0):

The grouping cannot be undone but is create a new table based off your underlying data and pivot the table to create a table so you can display as a table rather than a cross table.

Or add Protocol Status to your axis First([Protocol Status]) and make your first column that is grouped hidden by making the column width 0.